# C++ Multithreading with a fixed number of threads and a threadsafe queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to write a C++11/14 program in which a fixed number of threads (say 4) continuously take a work off a threadsafe queue, until there is no work left in the queue.

Threadsafe queue implementation:

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
  mutable std::mutex mut;
  std::queue<T> data_queue;
  std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
  threadsafe_queue() {}
  threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const &other)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
    data_queue = other.data_queue;
  }

  void push(T new_value)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    data_queue.push(new_value);
    data_cond.notify_one();
  }

  void wait_and_pop(T &value)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
    value = data_queue.front();
    data_queue.pop();
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
    std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
    data_queue.pop();
    return res;
  }

  bool try_pop(T &value)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if (data_queue.empty())
      return false;
    value = data_queue.front();
    data_queue.pop();
    return true;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if (data_queue.empty())
      return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
    data_queue.pop();
    return res;
  }

  bool empty() const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    return data_queue.empty();
  }
};
```

Function each thread runs:

```
void insertintobidask(std::string connstring, std::string ziparchivename, OFStreamWriter &errlog) { /.../ }
```

The Main in which the threads are supposed to take a work off the workqueue until there is no work left in the queue:

```
int main()
{
  std::ofstream errlog
  errlog.open("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/errlog.txt", std::ofstream::out);
  OFStreamWriter ofsw(&errlog);

  threadsafe_queue<std::string> wqueue;
  boost::filesystem::path fx_dir("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/Data");
  std::regex pattern_fx("HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_.*.zip");
  for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(fx_dir), end; iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string();
    if (std::regex_match(name, pattern_fx))
    {
      wqueue.push(name);
    }
  }

  /* Each thread below would run once, how do I modify it to make it continuously take a work off the queue and run until there is no work left in the queue?
  std::thread consumer1 (insertintobidask, "hostaddr=192.168.2.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J", wqueue.wait_and_pop(), &ofsw);
  std::thread consumer2 (insertintobidask, "hostaddr=192.168.2.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J", wqueue.wait_and_pop(), &ofsw);
  std::thread consumer3 (insertintobidask, "hostaddr=192.168.3.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J", wqueue.wait_and_pop(), &ofsw);
  std::thread consumer4 (insertintobidask, "hostaddr=192.168.3.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J", wqueue.wait_and_pop(), &ofsw);

  consumer1.join();
  consumer2.join();
  consumer3.join();
  consumer4.join();
  */

  errlog.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried another approach based on Nim's answer below and it works.

```
/* g++ -std=gnu++11 fxetl.cxx -o fxetl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lzip -lpqxx -lpq -pthread */

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <zip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "threadsafe_oerrlog.h"

void insertintobidask(pqxx::nontransaction &txn, std::string ziparchivename, OFStreamWriter &errlog)
{
  std::string fileyearmonth = ziparchivename.substr(27, 6);
  std::string ziparchivepath = "/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/Data/HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_AUDUSD_T" + fileyearmonth + ".zip";
  std::string zipfilepath = "DAT_ASCII_AUDUSD_T_" + fileyearmonth + ".csv";
  int err, r;
  char buffer[39];  // each line takes up 39 bytes

  struct zip *ziparchive = zip_open(ziparchivepath.c_str(), 0, &err);
  if (ziparchive)
  {
    struct zip_file *zipfile = zip_fopen(ziparchive, zipfilepath.c_str(), 0);
    if (zipfile)
    {
      while ((r = zip_fread(zipfile, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
      {
        std::string str(buffer);
        txn.exec("INSERT INTO fx.bidask VALUES('AUDUSD', to_timestamp(" +txn.quote(str.substr(0, 18)) + ", 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISSMS'), " + txn.quote(str.substr(19, 8)) + ", " + txn.quote(str.substr(28, 8)) + ")");
      }
      zip_fclose(zipfile);
      std::cout << fileyearmonth << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      errlog << zipfilepath;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    errlog << ziparchivepath;
  }

  zip_close(ziparchive);
}


int main()
{
  pqxx::connection conn1("hostaddr=192.168.2.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J");
  pqxx::nontransaction txn1(conn1);
  pqxx::connection conn2("hostaddr=192.168.3.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J");
  pqxx::nontransaction txn2(conn2);
  pqxx::connection conn3("hostaddr=192.168.2.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J");
  pqxx::nontransaction txn3(conn3);
  pqxx::connection conn4("hostaddr=192.168.3.104 port=5433 dbname=fxproj user=vorlket password=K1156312J");
  pqxx::nontransaction txn4(conn4);

  std::ofstream errlog("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/errlog.txt");
  OFStreamWriter ofsw(&errlog);

  boost::asio::io_service service1; // queue
  boost::asio::io_service service2;
  boost::asio::io_service service3;
  boost::asio::io_service service4;

  boost::filesystem::path fx_dir("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/Data");
  std::regex pattern_fx("HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_.*.zip");
  int serviceid = 0;
  for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(fx_dir), end; iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string();
    if (std::regex_match(name, pattern_fx))
    {
      serviceid %= 3;
      switch (serviceid)
      {
        case 0 :
          service1.post([&txn1, name, &ofsw]() { insertintobidask(txn1, name, ofsw); });
          break;
        case 1 :
          service2.post([&txn2, name, &ofsw]() { insertintobidask(txn2, name, ofsw); });
          break;
        case 2 :
          service3.post([&txn3, name, &ofsw]() { insertintobidask(txn3, name, ofsw); });
          break;
        case 3 :
          service4.post([&txn4, name, &ofsw]() { insertintobidask(txn4, name, ofsw); });
          break;
      }
      ++serviceid;
    }
  }

  std::thread t1([&service1]() { service1.run(); });
  std::thread t2([&service2]() { service2.run(); });
  std::thread t3([&service3]() { service3.run(); });
  std::thread t4([&service4]() { service4.run(); });

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();

}
```

Not sure which approach is faster, but I guess it depends on workload and platform one is working on. Worth a try to see which is faster. Any comments on which approach would be faster and whys are appreciated.

Comment: Questions like this are not welcome here and often results in heavy downvoting. Share us what you have implemented/tried till now and ask specific questions on what in your code is not working. Said that, welcome to SO!

Comment: Have a look at the [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). You'll find most of the stuff you need there.

Comment: Edited the question to share what I've tried.

Comment: Insertintobidask would have to execute some sort of loop

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is for learning/something where it's not fast enough, I'd delegate these crud operations to an existing mechanism. And I prefer to use `boost::asio::io_service` for this exact type of thing..

Code would be:

```
// Additional header
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::ofstream errlog
  errlog.open("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/errlog.txt", std::ofstream::out);
  OFStreamWriter ofsw(&errlog);

  boost::asio::io_service service; // queue
  boost::filesystem::path fx_dir("/home/vorlket/Desktop/Project/Code/Test/Data");
  std::regex pattern_fx("HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_.*.zip");
  for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(fx_dir), end; iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string();
    if (std::regex_match(name, pattern_fx))
    {
      service.post([name]() {
        // Do something with this file
      });
    }
  }
  // Now start-up n-threads to dispatch on the io_service
  std::thread t1([&service]() { service.run(); }); // this will dispatch on queue until there is nothing left to do...
  std::thread t2([&service]() { service.run(); });
  std::thread t3([&service]() { service.run(); });
  std::thread t4([&service]() { service.run(); });
  :

  // Wait for them to complete
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

Comment: Nim, I inserted a function call in the lambda but the threads don't seem to do any work. The code I tried are in the edited question above.

Comment: @vorlket, the changes look good, I can't see anything specifically wrong with it - may be some logging would help see where things are?

Comment: there was a mistake with relative/absolute path in the inserintobidask function. It works. Thanks for sharing.